# React-router-modal strange behavior - I need two clicks to go back, should be just one

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, react-modal

I used this npm package => `react-router-modal`( [doc](https://github.com/davidmfoley/react-router-modal) )

And here ([click](https://davidmfoley.github.io/react-router-modal-examples/)) in that example it takes only one click to go back from modal, but in my case, I must do the mouse click **two** times to go back, and I don't know why...

So maybe someone here can help me answer that question.

Quick demo of that issue -> https://youtu.be/szRC_K10pyA

Full project code -> [github](https://github.com/elminsterrr/beer-g3)

Two the most important components below:

Component `BeerListItem`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card, { CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card';
import { ModalContainer, ModalRoute } from 'react-router-modal';
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'react-router-modal/css/react-router-modal.css';
import './style.css';

import BeerProfile from '../BeerProfile';

class BeerListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.beerProfile = this.beerProfile.bind(this);
  }

  beerProfile() {
    const { beer } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <BeerProfile beer={beer} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { beer } = this.props;
    let cutStr = '';

    if (beer.name.length >= 27) {
      cutStr = `${beer.name.slice(0, 26)}...`;
    } else {
      cutStr = beer.name;
    }

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Link to={`/details/${beer.id}`}>
            <Card raised className="BeerListItem-main-card">
              <CardContent>
                <img
                  src={beer.image_url}
                  alt="beer"
                  className="BeerListItem-img"
                />
                <div className="BeerListItem-h2-and-p-container">
                  <h2 className="BeerListItem-h2">{cutStr}</h2>
                  <p className="BeerListItem-p">{beer.tagline}</p>
                </div>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </Link>

          <ModalRoute
            className="test-modal test-modal-foo"
            path={`/details/${beer.id}`}
            parentPath="/"
            component={this.beerProfile}
          />

          <ModalContainer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default BeerListItem;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Component `BeerProfile`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-router-modal';
import 'react-router-modal/css/react-router-modal.css';
import './style.css';

class BeerProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: true,
    };
    this.handleBackClick = this.handleBackClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleBackClick() {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);

    const { id } = this.props.beer;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.show && (
          <Modal onBackdropClick={this.handleBackClick}>
            <h3>Child elements</h3>
            <p>{id}</p>
          </Modal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BeerProfile;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

So when your modal is rendered, this is the console log I get,
[image]

So basically, two mounting occurs instead of one.

When I checked the codebase, I see that inside of `BeerListItem`, you use `ModalRoute` component from the package.

```
 <ModalRoute
   className="test-modal test-modal-foo"
   path={`/details/${beer.id}`}
   parentPath="/"
   component={this.beerProfile}
 />
```

And `this.beerProfile` renders the following

```
{this.state.show && (
  <Modal onBackdropClick={this.handleBackClick}>
    <h3>Child elements</h3>
    <p>{id}</p>
  </Modal>
```

`Modal` is also from the package itself

From documentation => [ModalRoute](http://ModalRoute%20A%20react-router%20Route%20that%20shows%20a%20modal%20when%20the%20location%20pathname%20matches.)

> ModalRoute A react-router Route that shows a modal when the location
>   pathname matches.

=> [Modal](http://Modal%20Renders%20its%20contents%20in%20a%20modal%20div%20with%20a%20backdrop.%20Use%20Modal%20if%20you%20want%20to%20show%20a%20modal%20without%20changing%20the%20route.)

> Modal Renders its contents in a modal div with a backdrop. Use Modal
>   if you want to show a modal without changing the route.

So basically it is an either/ or situation. If you want a modal with a changing url, you should use `ModalRoute`. If you only want modal, you should use `Modal`.

To my understanding, when you pass a `component` prop to `ModalRoute` it automatically wraps this components with a `Modal`

So what you need to do is, replacing

```
<div>
  {this.state.show && (
    <Modal onBackdropClick={this.handleBackClick}>
      <h3>Child elements</h3>
      <p>{id}</p>
     </Modal>
   )}
 </div>
```

with

```
  <div>
    <h3>Child elements</h3>
    <p>{id}</p>
  </div>
```

Ah also one small thing, you also need to get rid of `className`

```
<ModalRoute
            className="test-modal test-modal-foo"
```

when I check the codebase, I couldn't find styling related to these two.

After these changes, should work the way you expect.

One tip, `ModalRoute` also accepts `props` props. So instead of passing `this.beerProfile` you can do the following and it should also work

```
<ModalRoute
  path={`/details/${beer.id}`}
  props={this.props}
  parentPath="/"
  component={BeerProfile}
/>
```

Currently in my local, it's working as expected. Please try and let me know if it also works for you or not.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much!